# Did John Connor fall in love with a Terminator?

Tags: character, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In *[Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0851851/)*, did [John Connor](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000933/) fall in love with Cameron (Terminator) who came back from the future to protect him? Did Cameron also have feelings for John Connor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per below mentioned Emotional scenes we have to admit even Cameron is a robot but she had crush on john & john had Crush on Cameron. Down deep they love each other but never tell that to each other.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]